# When I run code written using the Windows api, it turns off as soon as it is turned on (in Visual Studio)

Tags: c, winapi, hook

I wrote this code using a windows api (a program that pops up a messagebox when I left-click) and when I run it, it seems to turn off as soon as it's turned on. )

(run with f5)

I think it's end, but I don't know what's wrong. Is it a code problem?

I use visual studio.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(_In_ int    nCode,
_In_ WPARAM wParam,
_In_ LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (wParam) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        MessageBoxA(0, "hi", "hanu", 0);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_Hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    HHOOK mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,MouseHookProc, hInstance, NULL);
}
```

Please point out if the question lacks information

Comment: Your program returns instantly, so what did you expect? Hooks only work while the program is running.

Comment: Your process terminates once it reaches the end of `WinMain`. You need to do something. Usually that would involve a message loop. I suggest that you read an introductory text on Win32 development.

Comment: I was hoping that when the program ran it would hook the mouse until it quits and left click to bring up a message window.

(I actually didn't understand your writing a bit, so it may be  irrelevant answe.)

Comment: "I was hoping that when the program ran it would hook the mouse until it quits" It does. But your program quits instantly. So you are kind of asking why `int main() { return 0; printf("hello"); }` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Thank you all. I will try it.

Comment: I linked to a topic about message loops in your previous question related to this.

Comment: A message loop is mandatory for most `SetWindowsHookEx()` hooks. Read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

1. a program that doesn't exit immediately because its main function returns
2. a message loop

The two condition are easily met by adding below code just after the `SetWindowsHookEx` call:

```
MSG msg;
while ( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) );
```

Have fun with the multiple Dialog Boxes you'll get!